# Java Mail Search Term is not working while fetching mails from IBM domino

Tags: jakarta-mail, ibm-domino

I am trying to fetch mails for a one particular date from IBM domino, but Java mails Search Term is not working.
I am able to fetch all the mails in the inbox, but I want to fetch only for one particular date.

here's my code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.search.*;
import java.text.*;

public class MyClass {
    
    public static void FetchMails(String date) {
    
            String host = "<IP of Host>";
            String username = "<username>";
                String password = "<password>";
                
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", host);
            properties.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "143");
                
            try {
                Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(properties,null);
                Store emailStore = emailSession.getStore("imap");   
                emailStore.connect(host, username, password);

                    //Getting Inbox folder
                Folder emailFolder = emailStore.getFolder("INBOX");
                emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
                    
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                    
                Date targetDateObj = sdf.parse(date);
                    
                SearchTerm searchTerm = 
                                    new SentDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.EQ, targetDateObj);
                    
                Message[] messages = emailFolder.search(searchTerm);
                    
                System.out.println("No Of Mails Fetched : "+messages.length);   
    
                    //closing
                    emailFolder.close(false);
                    emailStore.close();
            }
            catch(NoSuchProviderException nspe) {
                System.out.println(nspe.getMessage());
                nspe.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(MessagingException me){
                System.out.println(me.getMessage());
                    System.out.println(me.toString());
                    me.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ParseException pe) {
                System.out.println(pe.getMessage());
                pe.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
                FetchMails("31-08-2022");
        
    }

}
```

I am expecting that instead of fetching all the mails in the inbox, The code only fetches the mails received on one particular date.

I have tried using **properties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");**

but it seems like the code runs through all the mails but doesn't fetch any mail. I am getting zero fetched mails